# AVFoundation: Converting raw PCM samples to opus packets

Tags: swift, discord, avfoundation, core-audio, opus

I'm trying to capture microphone data using AVFoundation and AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate and converting it to opus packets for audio streaming.

I am confused in regards to how to convert the 512 PCM samples I get from `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` into an opus packet, which from what I've read has to have a length of 480 or 960 frames.

This is my encoder:

```
public extension DiscordOpusCodeable {
    ///
    /// Returns the maximum number of bytes that a frame can contain given a
    /// frame size in number of samples per channel.
    ///
    /// - parameter assumingSize: The size of the frame, in number of samples per channel.
    /// - returns: The number of bytes in this frame.
    ///
    func maxFrameSize(assumingSize size: Int) -> Int {
        return size * channels * MemoryLayout<opus_int16>.size
    }
}

///
/// An Opus encoder.
///
/// Takes raw PCM 16-bit-lesample data and returns Opus encoded voice packets.
///
open class DiscordOpusEncoder : DiscordOpusCodeable {
    // MARK: Properties

    /// The bitrate for this encoder.
    public let bitrate: Int

    /// The number of channels.
    public let channels: Int

    /// The maximum size of a opus packet.
    public var maxPacketSize: Int { return 4000 }

    /// The sampling rate.
    public let sampleRate: Int

    private let encoderState: OpaquePointer

    // MARK: Initializers

    ///
    /// Creates an Encoder that can take raw PCM data and create Opus packets.
    ///
    /// - parameter bitrate: The target bitrate for this encoder.
    /// - parameter sampleRate: The sample rate for the encoder. Discord expects this to be 48k.
    /// - parameter channels: The number of channels in the stream to encode, should always be 2.
    ///
    public init(bitrate: Int, sampleRate: Int = 48_000, channels: Int = 2, vbr: Bool = false) throws {
        self.bitrate = bitrate
        self.sampleRate = sampleRate
        self.channels = channels

        var err = 0 as Int32

        encoderState = opus_encoder_create(Int32(sampleRate), Int32(channels), OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP, &err)
        let err2 = opus_encoder_set_bitrate(encoderState, Int32(bitrate))
        let err3 = opus_encoder_set_vbr(encoderState, vbr ? 1 : 0)

        guard err == 0, err2 == 0, err3 == 0 else {
            destroyState()

            throw DiscordVoiceError.creationFail
        }
    }

    deinit {
        destroyState()
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    private func destroyState() {
        opus_encoder_destroy(encoderState)
    }

    ///
    /// Encodes a single frame of raw PCM 16-bit-le/sample LE data into Opus format.
    ///
    /// - parameter audio: A pointer to the audio data. Use `maxFrameSize(assumingSize:)` to find the length.
    /// - parameter frameSize: The size of the frame in samples per channel.
    /// - returns: An opus encoded packet.
    ///
    open func encode(_ audio: UnsafePointer<opus_int16>, frameSize: Int) throws -> [UInt8] {
        let output = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: maxPacketSize)
        let lenPacket = opus_encode(encoderState, audio, Int32(frameSize), output, opus_int32(maxPacketSize))

        defer { output.deallocate() }

        guard lenPacket > 0 else { throw DiscordVoiceError.encodeFail }

        return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: output, count: Int(lenPacket)))
    }
}
```

and this is my implementation of both delegate methods

```
   func engineNeedsData(_ engine: DiscordVoiceEngine) throws -> [UInt8] {
       
        let packet_samples = Array(self.samples.prefix(960))
        self.samples.removeFirst(960)
        return try self.opusEncoder.encode(packet_samples, frameSize: 960)
    }
```

```
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        let data = try! sampleBuffer.dataBuffer?.dataBytes()
        
        let uints = [UInt8](data!)
        var ints = uints.map { Int16($0) }
        
        self.samples.append(contentsOf: ints)
        print("got \(self.samples.count) samples in buffer")
 
    }
```

This project is based on the SwiftDiscord library found here: https://github.com/nuclearace/SwiftDiscord

I guess it must have something to do with the fact that

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to that problem?